# PostgreSQL Connections Not Closing in Flask Application while making DB queries inside a thread

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've built a Flask application that handles a large dataset of 2 billion records. The application is utilizing a Postgresql database hosted on DigitalOcean Managed Database. There's an endpoint for fetching data from the database, where I've implemented a thread for handling multiple database queries. However, after receiving the API response, the database connection remains idle and doesn't close.

Here's the structure of my Flask app along with the code snippet:

```
import queue
from threading import Thread
from flask import jsonify, request, g
from app.api import bp
from app import db

def download_all_data_thread(user_id, page, per_page, thread_response):
    app.app_context().push()
    response = []
    try:
        for ld in ModelA.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id).paginate(page=page, per_page=per_page, error_out=False).items:
            response.append({'id': ld.id})
        thread_response.put(response)
    except Exception as e:
        thread_response.put(str(e))
    finally:
        db.session.rollback()
        db.session.close()
        return True


def all_download_pagination(user_id: int) -> dict:
    thread_response = queue.Queue()
    result, threads = [], []
    for page in range(1, 6):
        t = Thread(target=download_all_data_thread, args=(user_id, page, 1000, thread_response))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
        val = thread_response.get_nowait()
        result.extend(val)
    return result


@bp.route("/get_data", methods=['POST'])
def getting_data_set():
    result = all_download_pagination(request.json['user_id'])
    return jsonify({'data': result, 'message': 'success', 'status': 200})
```

app/**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from config import Config_is


db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()

def create_app(config_class=Config_is):
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
    app.config.from_object(config_class)
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE'] = 300
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_PRE_PING'] = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE'] = 10
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    @app.teardown_request
    def teardown_request(exception=None):
        if db is not None:
            db.session.close()
            db.engine.dispose()
    from app.api import bp as api_bp
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/v1')

    return app
```

```
.
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── api1.py
│   │   ├── 
│   ├── models
│   │   ├── xxx.py
│   │   └── xxxx.py
│   ├── services
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── XXX.py
├── config.py
├── constants.py
├── requirements.txt
└── runserver.py
```

**NOTE**
The DB query is just a sample

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to properly manage database connections in this scenario to prevent them from staying idle.